# Detect whether overlay contains marker objects. Google Maps API V3, Drawing Library

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know this is probably a very basic problem but I'm new to javascript so any help would be much appreciated.

My task is to only display markers if they are inside the rectangle drawing object.

I use this to get the coordinates for the rectangle overlay:

var bounds = event.overlay.getBounds()

I need to pass this value into a new LatLngBounds object so I can use the contains method.

I tried myLatLngBounds.extend(bounds) but with no joy.

here is my loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {


    if (myLatLngBounds.contains(new google.maps.LatLng(-34.578109296711865, 150.2100400390625),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-34.01994620095979, 151.1878232421875)) ==true) {
        alert("yes");   
}
```

I simply need to replace the hardcoded coordinates with the bounds variable and I should be in business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rectangle.getBounds()` is already a `google.maps.LatLngBounds` object so you can just use `bounds.contains(marker.getPosition())` (unless I'm misunderstanding something here).